# Android MediaStore ActivityNotFound Exception, is a lie

Tags: android, video, android-intent, android-activity, mediastore

I am trying to load a list of files showing only video files in the system gallery.

```
final Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent1.setDataAndType(android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "video/*");
startActivityForResult(intent1, ACTIVITY_SELECT_VIDEO);
```

and I get `ActivityNotFound` exception on the debugger, causing the app to crash **BUT** on the actual phone the gallery does load showing only video files.

This is exactly how it works when loading only image files, except without the crashing.

How do I:

a) Load the proper gallery consistently

b) catch this exception or avoid it with a conditional statement, since it doesn't behave the same on all devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Load the proper gallery consistently

I would dump the `"video/*"` and just provide the `Uri` in the `Intent` constructor. `android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` should already be scoped for video, and that is the wrong MIME type for a collection.

Or, use `android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.CONTENT_TYPE` as the MIME type, which is not `"video/*"`.

> catch this exception

With a `try`/`catch` block, the same way you catch any exception in Java. `ActivityNotFoundException` is a `RuntimeException`.

> or avoid it with a conditional statement

Use `PackageManager` and either `queryIntentActivities()` or `resolveActivity()`.

Comment: what is the difference between using .CONTENT_TYPE vs .MIME_TYPE

Comment: @CQM: Well, for starters, there is no `android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE` in the SDK docs, and it is always easier to use things that exist. :-)

Comment: true true, I'm actually juggling between Image, Audio and Video. So many combinations that dont work across all devices. Trying to focus on one content type at a time